Hired for short term contract and was given notice
A third party recruiting agency contacted me about a specific job. I had an interview and accepted the job offer. It was for a 3 month contract with "a good chance of extension". The recruiter recently called me to say their client is giving me 2 weeks notice for dismissal. I am surprised that my manager who I speak with each day didn't say anything. The recruiter said that the manager knew I was being dismissed. Should I follow up with anyone in writing? How should I ask for a reference?
For context, the recruiting agency hired me as their own employee, and the client that I work exclusively for considers me a contractor. The manager has a very hands off approach and is not very familiar with the work that I do. The job is very independent and I don't work closely with anyone.
Also, the manager had been saying he would like me to increase the number of tickets I close per day. This is basically the only stat he cares about. I feel like I've already been working extra. How should I handle my workload considering the job is coming to an end? I've created several automation tools for the job that I haven't told anyone about. I think they would be very helpful for the other people on the team. The company is large and I think I may be a better fit for a different department. Should I try to network internally?

I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but there is some sort of ambiguity as to who my manager is. My contract specifies one person who I have meetings with and report to. Apparently he has officially been replaced by another manager (who I occasionally spoke with) but I guess is just helping out by continuing the current duties until the new one is ready.

I feel I can answer parts of this - but you have asked multiple questions in one, which we tend to discourage. I would recommend clarifying exactly what question you want answers to - is it about what happened (VTC - only your manager can answer that - but I think we can infer based on your other question) or is it about re-applying etc (which we may be able to give advise on)

In the next 2 weeks. Increase your output. You never know what might happen.

@TheDemonLord This question is also a continuation of a string of questions the OP has asked recently about the same position.


For context, the recruiting agency hired me as their own employee, and the client that I work exclusively for considers me a contractor.


The recruiter recently called me to say they are giving me 2 weeks notice for dismissal.

Assuming "they" refers to the client (not the recruiter) then you weren't being given notice of dismissal. The contract is between your employer (the recruiter) and your client, and it's your employer who was given a notice that your detachment to work for this client was coming to an end.
At the end of the day, as a detached consultant you are not your client's employee, nor do you have a contract with them. The relationship between you and your client should be managed by your employer (the recruiter), so you should be asking them what it is they want you to do during this notice period.
The reason you need to talk to your employer is because there are several different options on the table, and your employer will have different expectations of you and their ongoing relationship with this client.
You didn't get fired. Your client simply ended a contract with your employer, which happened to be your assignment. The next step here is to ask your employer what they want you to work on.

The way the recruiter phrased it, was that the decision was made by the client and he was just passing on the message.

@ClanLatin: You're just agreeing with my point. Detached consultancy deals with a weird distinction where your practical employer and your actual employer are different, and the language hasn't caught up to this. For all practical purposes, you will stop working for the client because they chose to end it. But since you're a detached consultant, you were not fired, your assignment merely ended (with a notice period included). Source: was a detached consultant for close to 10 years.

Check this with your actual employer. It's certainly possible that your recruiting agency has fired you, but the way you are describing it definitely makes it sound like the only thing that has happened is that the client has terminated their contract with the recruiting agency. Finding out which is actually the case is your top priority.

@ClanLatin, it sounds like "disguised employment" where the reality is that the client is the ultimate controlling employer, whereas your agency is a middle-man that takes a cut of your wages. Nevertheless, you don't know how much they were being charged, and you may be fired because you don't live up to the grade the middleman is charging for, rather than because you don't meet standards in your own terms.


The recruiter recently called me to say their client is giving me 2 weeks notice for dismissal. I am surprised that my manager who I speak with each day didn't say anything. The recruiter said that the manager knew I was being dismissed. Should I follow up with anyone in writing?

That's his words, something could be "lost in translation". You should mention it to the manager. At best casually, on a meeting, not in writing. Something along the line "Since the company resigned from my services, which tasks do you want me to focus on for the remaining time?" (do not say "yours company", that's confrontative). That will let the manager know that you're being fired by them, in case you're having doubts about the situation. Make sure you never even imply that someone is acting malicious - just give out all information and let them handle the case.

How should I ask for a reference?

That depends who do you want (or can request) the reference from. If you think it's OK to ask for references from the client, ask the manager you're speaking to. A good topic to bring up your termination.

How should I handle my workload considering the job is coming to an end?

Keep up the same level. Be professional to the very end. If in doubt, do a bit more.

I've created several automation tools for the job that I haven't told anyone about. I think they would be very helpful for the other people on the team.

Hmm, if you have created an automation, and yet you're still feeling falling behind and have to put out extra, that could mean several things. Either your automation is crap, or they are comparing you to someone with much better automation, or they have completely unrealistic expectations that can never be met. In any case, a productivity tips from someone they perceive as underperforming, won't be welcomed. I'm not saying that you are underperforming. I'm saying that this is how you look like from the other side.

The company is large and I think I may be a better fit for a different department. Should I try to network internally?

Do you really want to work in a company that has only one thing to tell you: "work faster"? You've said you don't have contact with anyone there except your manager. That doesn't look like a networking opportunity.

In your situation I would have a talk with the manager.  Be unemotional and ask for feedback.  Be open to feedback.  By the way the feedback of "close more tickets" is not actionable so not good feedback.  It could actually be more representative of the stress he is under rather than anything to do with you.
I would not bother telling anyone else about the automation tools other than for your own benefit.  Keep a copy and you may need such for your next job.  They will probably require modification, but it is helpful to have a start.
Networking within the company is a great idea and had used it successfully in the past.  I was a contractor with a well known large company and my manager gave me the ultimatum of come on full time, or have your contract canceled.  The full time pay was very low.  While I asked my contract company to look for opportunities for me I had to find my next job myself.
My contract company actually listed the job I ended up with, but I had to tell me to put me in for it.  Despite me having an excellent reputation with everyone at the contract company, they did not make the connection.  It was even with the same company and I got a great reference from my old manager.
The moral of this story it is incumbent upon you to find your next position and improve in your career.  This is why you should ask for and implement feedback.  You should network.  You should be looking for your next job.
As far as closing out your work I would not "kill" myself, but do a good job of continuing to close tickets.  Certainly no overtime or undue stress.

Your employer has a contract with a customer. That contract dictates the relationship between them. The customer can have little power over who is working on the contract; or they can have total power; and everything in between. The customer has decided that you and maybe others in that contract are no longer needed.
There is a "contract" between you and your employer. That agreement, in addition to labor laws, will dictate what might happen next. Your days could be numbered, or you might be safe for a while.
If your employer thinks you have the skills they can rent out, they will keep you even when they don't have to. If you are new, or they don't see that your skills are useful, won't keep you any longer than they have to.
Start looking. Also talk to your employer.
